# iptables rules for dockerized prometheus stack and swarm

Tags: iptables, docker, port, prometheus

OS: ubuntu
Everything runns in containers (run via docker stack deploy)
2 servers running separate swarm

1. server - running grafana + prometheus (ip 1.1.1.1)
2. server - running node_exporter + cadvisor (ip 2.2.2.2)

Need to setup IPTABLES:

On 1st server:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 9100 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 2.2.2.2. -p tcp --dport 9100 -j ACCEPT
```

***(9100 is node_exporter port)***

When node_exporter iptables are setup as above everything looks just ok and I am happy. So I want to setup the same for cadvisor.

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -j DROP
iptables -I FORWARD -s 2.2.2.2. -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

***(8080 is cadvisor port)***

When its setup iptables for cadvisor as posted above it does not work.

When I set it up again as:

```
iptables -I FORWARD -p tcp --dport 8080 -j ACCEPT
```

everything works fine - but I do not want the port to be exposed to the world.

Please help